# Can't import Orekit - 'DLL load failed'

Tags: java, python, anaconda

I try to run Orekit library through python. I use Anaconda, as proposed in [official tutorial](https://www.orekit.org/forge/projects/orekit-python-wrapper/wiki/Installation). Unfortunately, I come across following error as soon as I try to `import orekit` in python 2.7 console:

```
In [1]: import orekit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-307c30f2343b> in <module>()
----> 1 import orekit

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\orekit\__init__.py in <module>()
      2 os.environ["PATH"] = r"C:/Anaconda2\Library\jre\bin\server" + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
      3
----> 4 import os, _orekit
      5
      6 __dir__ = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

ImportError: DLL load failed: Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego modu│u.
```

I've already added required 2 environmental paths and installed JDK which is located in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102`. I've also installed JCC and Orekit through Anaconda. I use Windows 10 64 bit and python 2.7.

Do you have any suggestions what might gone wrong? How to run it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install jdk through Anaconda by:

```
conda install -c cyclus java-jdk
```

I found it in official [mailing list thread](https://www.orekit.org/wws/arc/orekit-users/2016-07/msg00001.html).